# Short story, possibly in a Weird Tales collection: prince imprisoned after his castle was invaded by magicians, eventually gets revenge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I want to say I read this short story in a *Weird Tales* collection but can't be sure.

It's about a prince whose father was murdered after the castle was invaded by weird magic users. The prince was locked in a dungeon (I think) but in the end got revenge.

I think this character was a lesser known character from a famous author... I was thinking Robert Howard but can't find any proof. It was a lot like Conan as far as a warrior Prince and I think he had blonde hair.

Comment: I found it, it is Prince Raynor. Written by Henry Kuttner.

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 5):

Per [the OP's comment above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54647/help-with-a-story-title-character-name#comment106233_54647), the correct answer was [*Prince Raynor*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1425922), a collection of two stories by Henry Kuttner.

From a [blurb found on bookmate.com](https://bookmate.com/books/zJ0ML55O):

> When Robert E. Howard died in 1936, some of the greatest science-fiction and fantasy writers stepped into the void to pen amazing tales of swords and sorcery.  Weird Tales published these two stories by iconic author Henry Kuttner, perfect for fans of Conan the Barbarian, and vital for every fantasy reader.  Depicting a brutal world of swords and magic, with a hint of the Lovecraft mythos, Kuttner unleashes tales as vital in today’s Game of Thrones world as they were when they first published. Stories include: ["Cursed be the City"](https://archive.org/details/Strange_Stories_v01n02_1939-04),  ["The Citadel of Darkness"](https://archive.org/details/Strange_Stories_v02n01_1939-08) [links to the Internet Archive].

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to the [*Chronicles of Amber*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/316876.The_Chronicles_of_Amber) by Roger Zelazny.

In particular the part about the prince being in the dungeon and then escaping to have his revenge. Corwin is the name of the Prince of Amber.

Comment: It's not that, I already checked. I know it was in a hardback collection of short stories and the preface said something about the main character being lesser known and I dont think there was many stories written. I wanna say it was ator or something like that.

Comment: I will double check, I may has missed something. Ill let you know, Thanks.  Ok, I checked and it isnt that. This is a short story and it is strictly dungeons and dragons type fantasy. I think he was maybe more like Heman... hair, muscle, etc. As I said it was either weird tales or rivals of weird tales book, I am pretty sure. I read it 6 years ago.